# Function Composition of JavaScript and Haskell

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

In JavaScript we can define [function composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition_%28computer_science%29) as using a function which takes two functions f and g, to produce a new function:

```
function o(f, g) {
  return function(x) {
   return f(g(x));
  }
 }
```

This seems obvious, but my question is, does the runtime interpreter/compiler **actually calculate** f(g(x))?

Say we have some large data like an array with many elements, and is the previously composed function o as the **f(g(x))** by the prior calculation faster than uncomposed **f(g(x))** ?

Perhaps, in this case, **o(f, g)** as merely a macro expression of **f(g(x))**?

And if it's a macro, perhaps, the performance doesn't make much difference?

It may depends on the runtime environment, I especially interested in V8 engine for Chrome/node.js.

Haskell as a language of lazy evaluation strategy theoretically compose functions, am I correct? Does GHC actually calculate to compose functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the function call `o(f, g)` will return exactly the anonymous function:

```
function (x) {
    return f(g(x));
}
```

Then, only at the time, when you call that anonymous function, `g(x)` will execute and then `f` will execute on the result of `g(x)`. Every time you call that anonymous function both `g` and `f` execute, one after the other. So the using the composed function will be just a little slower than manually calling `f(g(x))` everywhere in your code due to the slight overhead of the extra anonymous function.

Example:

```
function o(f, g){
    return function(x) {
        return f(g(x));
    }
}

function addTo5(x){
    return x + 5;
}

function multiplyBy(x){
    return function(y){
        return x*y;
    }
}

var composed = o(multiplyBy, addTo5);
composed(5)(3); // Slightly slower than multiplyBy(addTo5(5))(3)
```

### jsperf

Answer (score 0):

No calculation is performed until you call the composed function returned by `o`. This new function just keeps track of what `f` and `g` are, and invoke them when you pass `x` in, evaluating and returning the final result.